# 404 Error installing Meteor on Mac OS X 10.10.5

Tags: meteor

I was trying to install meteor.js on my Mac using the command given on the Meteor website:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

However I get:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6117    0  6117    0     0   3645      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  3643
Downloading Meteor distribution

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Installation failed.
```

Tried googling this but couldn't find an answer, anyone knows what going on?

Comment: This is URL in question: https://d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net/packages-bootstrap/1.2/meteor-bootstrap-os.osx.x86_64.tar.gz

Looking at just https://d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net/packages-bootstrap it seems like the latest version for `os.osx.x86_64` is `1.1.0.3`

Comment: Should be fixed now, I've uploaded the correct files to the correct place.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with 1.2.0.2 version. The workaround below solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

So, not sure if this is an official solution but I was able to get Meteor 1.2 by first installing Meteor 1.1.0.3, which was the latest version I saw on the https://d3sqy0vbqsdhku.cloudfront.net/ for Mac OS X (or any OS).

However, to get that version I first had to save the shell code from https://install.meteor.com to a local file, and then manually change

`RELEASE="1.2"` on line 25 to RELEASE="1.1.0.3"

After install Meteor using this version, then I ran a manual `meteor update` in the terminal

I don't really know why this is the case but if anyone else is seeing this problem then hope this helps

Comment: I was releasing the new version today, and forgot to upload the appropriate file. I expect it will be fixed within the hour.

Comment: @stubailo It's happening again today.

Comment: Its happening to me as well while deploying in heroku

Answer (score 0):

i have fix the version in order for you guys to download

Solution to install latest meteor:

`$ curl http://augmify.com/meteorInstall.sh | sh`

you should see this result:

```
    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left          Speed
    100  6122  100  6122    0     0   654k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--          664k
    Downloading Meteor distribution
    ########################################################################                 100.0%

    Meteor 1.1.0.3 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
    Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your convenience.

    To get started fast:

      $ meteor create ~/my_cool_app
      $ cd ~/my_cool_app
      $ meteor

    Or see the docs at:

      docs.meteor.com
```

then do

`$ meteor update`

you should see this result:

```
    Installed. Run 'meteor update --release 1.2.0.4-logging.0' inside of a particular project directory to update that project to Meteor 1.2.0.4-logging.0.
```

Comment: @Sandeep.sarkar i updated the version and gave a guide how to update to the latest by install the previous one, i uploaded the edited meteorinstall.sh to my server, so you guys can just curl from it.

Answer (score 0):

We need first to know what this command does,

first it download a file, using this link https://install.meteor.com/.
then execute it, that's it.

So read the sh file,

there is a link where it download a file. it's
*

> [https://static-meteor.netdna-ssl.com/packages-bootstrap/${RELEASE}/meteor-bootstrap-${PLATFORM}.tar.gz](https://static-meteor.netdna-ssl.com/packages-bootstrap/$%7BRELEASE%7D/meteor-bootstrap-$%7BPLATFORM%7D.tar.gz)

- 

this link is related to your system. **${RELEASE}** is the version you want to download and **${PLATFORM}** is the system where u want to install into it,

it can be os.linux.x86_32 os.linux.x86_64.

Check your system and the file and download Meteor directly in the browser.

**This question may be so old but i still facing the same problem and i solved it this way.